# WordPress - Why are my variables undefined when using a function to hook them into the page?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have data from the customizer using the Kirki framework and when I assign he variable on the page itself they show without any issues. However, I want to put them in a function and use an action hook to so the variables can be assigned in functions.php and used on the home page.

functions.php code:

```
function jp_frontpage_data() {
    $hero_title             = get_theme_mod( 'hero_title', 'Creativity Starts Here' );
    $hero_subtitle          = get_theme_mod( 'hero_subtitle', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.' );
    $hero_bg_overlay        = get_theme_mod( 'hero_background_overlay', 'on' );
    // More variables here
}
add_action( 'before-main-front', 'jp_frontpage_data' );
```

front-page.php code:

```
get_header( 'front' );

do_action( 'before-main-front' );
```

Error message that shows for every variable I use is `Notice: Undefined variable`.

Comment: Because you need to make them global by using the `global` keyword before each one e.g `global $hero_title = get_theme_mod(...);`, you could probably also use `extract()` to add them to the symbol table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try defining the variables before the function and just assign an empty string to each variable.